# sql insert select combinations

Tags: sql, select, insert

I have two tables: table1 has among others a column where an id1 is saved. Table2 has 
among others a column where id2 is saved. 
Now I want all combinations of these two tables and insert it into another empty table.
The problem is that another column should represent the sum of all combinations 
already mentioned. 
Here is what I tried, but did not work:

```
INSERT INTO cards (cardid, color, value)
SELECT   mult.colorid + 1000 * mult.valueid, mult.colorid, mult.valueid
FROM (
        SELECT c.colorid 
        FROM color c
        UNION ALL
        SELECT v.valueidid 
        FROM value v
        )  mult
```

Comment: "*did not work*" is not a valid error message in any DBMS I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all combinations between two tables , do a CROSS JOIN between them

```
INSERT INTO cards (cardid, color, value)
Select c.colorid + 1000 * v.valueid, c.colorid, v.valueid
FROM   color c CROSS JOIN value v
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO cards (cardid, color, value)
SELECT   c.colorid + 1000 * v.valueid, c.colorid, v.valueid
FROM color c, value v
```